# Python: wait for sigchild outside main thread

Tags: python, asynchronous, signals

I'm working on a task scheduler which should run tasks described in xml file.
Scheduler should be multithread and asynchronous to minimize overhead spent in waiting.
The problem is that `os.wait*` throws `OSError` when no child is running.

So, here is my code:

```
print("Waiting")
try:
    (pid, exit_status) = os.waitpid(-1, 0)
    exit_status >>= 8
except OSError:
    print("Got error")
    #when wait is called, and there is no child processes
    #OSError is being raised
    import time
    time.sleep(1)               
    continue
```

I wonder if it is possible to eliminate `sleep()` call.

Comment: You should consider using something more sophisticated like ``twisted``. Here is a good post regarding this topic: http://jessenoller.com/blog/2009/02/11/twisted-hello-asynchronous-programming

Comment: I think we need clarification here.  How is this 'pid' started/run?  And how does the above code fit into the rest of your project?

Comment: I use `subprocess.Popen` to run processes. I have one thread to run tasks, and another one to wait for them to finish. Here is a link to repo https://github.com/georgthegreat/sched/blob/master/scheduler/local.py. I've already found solution with threading.Semaphore(), but I still wonder if there is a way to handle signal outsidethe main thread.